# How do I make a command with my own prefix?

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I need the `help` command to have its own prefix.

For example, the bot's standard prefix is `!`, and for the `help` command I want to make the prefix `.` . I didn't find anything in the documentation except for the brige commands, but that's not what I need.

My code:

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, help_command=None)

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    #long embed
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix)

> This prefix could either be a string to indicate what the prefix should be, or a **callable that takes in the bot as its first parameter and discord.Message as its second parameter and returns the prefix.**

Example Code:

```py
def get_prefix(bot: commands.Bot, msg: discord.Message):  # callable for prefix
    if msg.content.startswith(".help"):  # if it starts with the help command
        return "."
    return "!"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)  # command_prefix argument changed
```

Also, discord.py have a framework for creating a help command via [`commands.HelpCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=helpcommand#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand).
It provides useful features such as retrieving the command's docstring for help message and generating command usage help from the function signature.
It is not a good idea to define your own help command by creating an ordinary command named "help".